# Profiling the initial PHP file, anyone, that get like 10 seconds to load

Tags: plugins, performance

I got a Worpress to improve, locate on a shared cloud server where we do not have so much control (cron jobs, and a limited cPanel)

thing is, that whatever page I call, it takes like like 10 seconds

probably a pluging, or just slow server, chache can not be enabled becouse a plugin need to recalculate things each time (yes, crappy setup)

within next month we plan a migration, but for now we will like to speed up things

there is like 3 or 4 plugins for performance, but nothing seems to help

can I profile in some way the PHP file to see what is doing that take so long time?

( maybe we could live also with some caching mechanism that caches pages each 5 minutes or so, not sure if that exist, but only maybe, we should do some tests before)

Comment: Try [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/), it gives you a lot of extra information to debug long loading times.

Comment: not really what i was loking for; I mean also from the php perspective, how long takes each php, what chain of calls, etc.. also db, of course

Comment: my problem relays mosrtly on Time To First Byte, with aroun 10 seconds on landing, and 15 to 25 seconds on wp-admin

Comment: QueryMonitor, on queries, sows about 100 , but only 0.07 secs, so thats not adding so much